# phpmyadmin 6.0.1 Extension for TYPO3 11.5, immediate crash after install

Tags: phpmyadmin, typo3-11.x

I am using TYPO3 11.5.33 instance in composer mode.
The installation of phpmyadmin 6.0.1 via composer doesn't indicate any problems,
but when i try to reload the back end throws an exception.

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1476107295: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "extConf" in /var/www/webserver.stfc/public_html/typo3conf/ext/phpmyadmin/ext_tables.php line 22 | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception thrown in file /var/www/webserver.stfc/public_html/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php in line 137. Requested URL: http://webserver.stfc/typo3/module/system/BelogLog
```

A similar ISSUE was already posted in the git page earlier this year, but the problem is yet not addressed in official release.

Someone had the problem and managed to fix it ?

I'm currently trying to find something in the documentation that could help, but no luck yet.